# Elasticsearch query_string in multi_match

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query in my ElasticSearch (I'm using version 1.6) application:

```
{
    "query":{
        "span_multi":{
            "match":{
                "query_string": {
                    "fields": ["field_name"],
                    "query": "*term*"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it works fine. As soon as I add another field to the `fields` parameter, like

```
{
    "query":{
        "span_multi":{
            "match":{
                "query_string": {
                    "fields": ["field_name", "another_field_name"],
                    "query": "*term*"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
spanMultiTerm [match] must be of type multi term query
```

What am I doing wrong? How could I fix this with the least impact on my original query?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use multi match query:

```
{
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "*term*", 
      "fields": [ "field_name", "another_field_name" ] 
    }
}
```